# ubuntu gnome ,what is short cut key to show/ hide left bottom lancher?

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, gnome-shell

I am new to GNOME.
I noticed the left bottom launcher (task bar ?) that contains input method, autokey or dropbox icons.
To hide this, I can press the `<`-icon, but I wonder what is keyboard short cut to do this and what its name is.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the [message tray](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-notifications.html.en)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is known as the Legacy Tray. It used to be known as the Message Tray and had a shortcut of <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>. Now the Message Tray has moved to the dropdown from the clock on the top panel and took that shortcut with it, and the GNOME documentation does not list a new shortcut for the legacy tray. [This Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/66m7oe/keyboard_shortcut_to_showhide_the_legacy_tray/dgjzhe0/) has a command that can be used to show the tray.

I just move the icons in the legacy tray to the top panel using [the TopIcons extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/) and ignore it.

Comment: thanks  for reply .  that is answer that I am looking for!

Comment: and I acknowledge  for two solutions. maybe, I will use TopIcons extension

Comment: Or use **TopIcons Plus** for some extra options: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/